# React prerender.io fetch as google is not working

Tags: reactjs, express, seo, google-search-console, prerender

I am using prerender for `ExpressJS` app. I've kept `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` in `index.html` page. It is working fine when I am using `mywebsite.com/?_escape_fragment_=`, but when I use fetch as google for `mywebsite.com/` I see no data. But for the ugly format with `?_escape_fragment_=` it is working like charm.

Will Googlebot crawl `mywebsite.com` as `mywebsite.com/?_escape_fragment_=` when it is being indexed or I need to do something for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetch as Google has a known issue where it doesn't automatically check for the fragment meta tag. If you enter `?_escaped_fragment_=` on the end of the URL in Fetch as Google, it should see the prerendered page correctly.

The real Googlebot does not have that bug, and they will see the fragment meta tag and successfully crawl the `?_escaped_fragment_=` URL on their own.

Comment: is this still the case?  it seems a huge (HUGE) "known issue" to have never been addressed (or officially acknowledged) by google?

Comment: John Mueller mentions it in this answer: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/YaOZrKGYrGA